# If I use a CPU with more cores than the specs of the motherboard allow, what will happpen?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, xeon, dell-precision, cpu-cores

I have a Dell Precision T3600 with a Xeon [E5-1607](http://ark.intel.com/fr/products/64619/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-1607-10M-Cache-3_00-GHz-0_0-GTs-Intel-QPI) (quad core) and want to upgrade the CPU for a [E5-2658v3](http://ark.intel.com/fr/products/81905/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2658-v3-30M-Cache-2_20-GHz) (12 cores). The motherboard of the T3600 seem to only support up to 6 cores according to the Datasheet. What will happen if I put this 12 cores CPU with this motherboard?

Comment: Those are entirely different sockets.  A motherboard isn't limited to a cou with only a certain amount of cores it's limited by the socket.  Those two CPUs are not compatible with one another due to their socket

Comment: "*The motherboard of the T3600 seem to only support up to 6 cores according to the Datasheet.*" Got a link to that datasheet? I've never seen such a thing.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @ David: Here is a [link](http://www.levnapc.cz/ProductsFiles/Dell-Precision-T3600-technicke-specifikace-en.pdf). @ Ramhound: Sockets are FCLGA2011-3 and FCLGA2011. Are these two different sockets? I have seen that they are mechanically identical, but electronically different. Does that mean they are not compatible?